# Inverted exclamation and question mark in ISO-8859

Tags: linux, bash, utf-8, sed, iso-8859-1

I need to replace inverted exclamation and inverted question marks in subtitle files so they display correctly on my TV. The files work correctly in ISO-8859, but I can't remove the marks.

The first solution was to use the command '`sed`':

```
sed s/\¿|¡//g "$FILE"
```

This works for files in UTF-8, but what would be the right solution for files in ISO-8859?

`sed 's/\xBF//g'`, for example, doesn't work.

Comment: Why not use `iconv(1)` to convert the file?

Comment: Because it shows me wrong accents of UTF-8 subtitles.

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding, not an alphabet. "¡" and "¿" are both found in ISO 8859-1, which is another encoding.

Comment: I know. But the code for "¡" and "¿" is not the same.

Comment: Just to clarify, does your TV work with ISO 8859-1, or can it only understand ASCII?

Comment: The code for inverted question mark in ISO 8859-1 is 0xBF; the code for INVERTED QUESTION MARK in Unicode is U+00BF, which is encoded in UTF8 as 0xC2 0xBF.  The code for inverted exclamation mark in ISO 8859-1 is 0xA1; the code for INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK in Unicode is U+00A1, which is encoded in UTF8 as 0xC2 0xA1.  Note that 0xC2 in ISO 8859-1 is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX or U+00C2 in Unicode.  You have to decide, carefully, which code set you are working with and how you want to edit the data.  If it is UTF8 data, you must ensure two bytes are removed each time.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. `sed 's/\xBF//g'` correctly removes ¿ from an input string in iso-8859-1 encoding, using `GNU sed 4.2.2`, even with a unicode locale selected. Are you certain the file is encoded in iso-8859-1? Can you be more precise about what you are doing and in what way you believe the  `sed` command you provide "doesn't work"?

Comment: @rici ! The quotes! I had written the script whitout quotes! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this command, your <kbd>\</kbd> is removed by bash before the argument is passed to sed:

```
sed s/\¿//g "$FILE"
```

That doesn't matter, because ¿ is not a bash metacharacter and it does not require quoting. However, if you write this:

```
sed s/\xBF//g "$FILE"
```

it won't do what you expect; bash will replace `\x` with `x` leaving sed with the command `s/xBF//g`, which is probably not what you wanted to do.

You must either write:

```
sed 's/\xBF//g'
```

or

```
sed s/\\xBF//g
```

The command posted will not work, though:

```
sed s/\¿|¡//g "$FILE"
```

<kbd>|</kbd> is a bash metacharacter, and it must therefore be quoted or escaped. Also, `sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions (BREs) by default, which means that you must write `\|` to express alternation. That means that you would have to type:

```
    sed 's/¿\|¡//g' "$FILE"
```

or

```
    sed s/¿\\\|¡//g "$FILE"
```